# How to parameterize KubernetesPodOperator's resources in Airflow 2.4.3 with params?

Tags: airflow, jinja2, kubernetespodoperator

I have an Airflow DAG that uses a KubernetesPodOperator to run a containerized task. I would like to be able to parameterize the resources (memory and CPU) allocated to the container, so that I can change them depending on the specific DAG run.

I tried using Airflow's params to define the container_resources argument in the KubernetesPodOperator, but I couldn't find a way to reference the parameters in the dictionary. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators import KubernetesPodOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 3, 7),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
}

with DAG(
    'my_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    catchup=False,
    params={
        "request_memory": Param("2000", type="string"),
        "request_cpu": Param("4000", type="string"),
        "limit_memory": Param("4G", type="string"),
        "limit_cpu": Param("5000", type="string"),
    }
) as dag:

    task = KubernetesPodOperator(
        task_id='my_task',
        name='my_task',
        image='my_image:latest',
        namespace='my_namespace',
        image_pull_policy='Always',
        is_delete_operator_pod=True,
        container_resources={
            'request_memory': '{{ params.request_memory }}',# tried dag.params["request_memory"],
            'limit_memory': '{{ params.limit_memory }}' 
            'request_cpu': '{{ params.request_cpu }}',
            'limit_cpu': '{{ params.limit_cpu }}',
        },
    )
```

However, the Jinja template is not replaced.

Is there a way to reference the DAG's params inside the container_resources dictionary in the KubernetesPodOperator? If not, what would be the best way to parameterize the resources allocated to the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the  apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes==4.2.2
the container_resources was not yet templated

I updated to  apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes==5.2.2
and it worked

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is not rendered could be because you have params dictionary as `request_memory` and in Jinja you are referencing as `params.mem_request`.  If you replaced it with `params.request_memory`, the rendering might work fine.

However, according to [doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/_api/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/operators/kubernetes_pod/index.html), it says `container_resources` should be a type of `k8s.V1ResourceRequirements`, so you probably should create this object.

```py
resources = k8s.V1ResourceRequirements(
    limits={
        'cpu': '{{ params.limit_cpu }}',
        'memory': '{{ params.limit_memory }}'
    },
    requests={
        'cpu': '{{ params.request_cpu }}',
        'memory': '{{ params.request_memory }}'
    }
)

task = KubernetesPodOperator(
    ...
    container_resources=resources
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. about your first suggestion I did a mistake when writing the question

 the second  I tried but it's was unsuccessful the template is not replaced

the pod definition is rendered as follows : 
 "resources": {  "limits": { "cpu": "{{ params.limit_cpu }}", "memory": "{{ params.limit_memory }}" }

Comment: Have you tried with `V1ResourceRequirements` and where you are looking at the rendered string (Rendered Template tab or Task Instance Details tab)?

Comment: I tried Yes at the time it did not work, but the code I presented worked for me when I updated to the 5.2.2 the provider  apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes